# Spring MVC - Bean not available with @Autowired

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, annotations, datasource, autowired

I'm having some trouble getting a data source bean, defined in an xml file, into a class in Spring using @Autowired annotation.

Would anyone have an idea what's happening here? It seems as though dataSource in the *Impl class is not being wired in.

dao-context.xml

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/spring" />
    <property name="username" value="user" />
    <property name="password" value="1234" />
</bean>
```

PersonDaoImpl.java

```
public class PersonDaoImpl implements PersonDao {

@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;  
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate();


public DataSource getDataSource() {
    return dataSource;
}

public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    System.out.println("SETTING DATA SOURCE");
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
}

public List<Person> getPersonList() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public void savePerson(Person person) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public Person getPersonById(int id) {
    System.out.println("Getting Person: " + id);        
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getPersonCount(){
    String sql = "SELCECT COUNT(*) FROM PERSON";
    jdbcTemplate.setDataSource(getDataSource());
    int count = jdbcTemplate.queryForInt(sql);
    System.out.println("Count of Person: " + count);
    return count;
}

public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate() {
    return jdbcTemplate;
}

public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
    this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
}
```

}

...and finally, the exception.

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No DataSource specified
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:894)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No DataSource specified
    org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:97)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:382)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:456)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:464)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:472)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:477)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForInt(JdbcTemplate.java:486)
    com.myPackage.rest.dao.impl.PersonDaoImpl.getPersonCount(PersonDaoImpl.java:50)
    com.myPackage.rest.HomeController.home(HomeController.java:36)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:212)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:900)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, cheers.

Comment: Is PersonDaoImpl a Spring ressources? Can you post the entire dao-context.xml file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your data source needs to be set in the JdbcTemplate (I don't see you doing that). Also since you put the `@Autowired` annotation on the field, I don't think it uses the setter so that would be why your setDataSource method is not being called. Since your exception indicates that you called jdbcTemplate.execute and dataSource is null, this makes sense.

If you look here: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html there is an example of autowiring a data source, but the idea is:

```
public class  MyDao {

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }
}
```

Comment: jdbc template can be a singleton as well

Comment: In my example, if the dao is singleton so is jdbTemplate, because in practice sstDataSource is only called once after construction.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. Have no idea how I'd missed this example in the Spring docs.

Answer (score 1):

Right, thanks to the two replies I've got this working.

dao-context (as above, with this added):

```
    <bean id="personDao" class="com.mypackage.rest.dao.impl.PersonDaoImpl">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>
```

Impl class

```
@Repository
public class PersonDaoImpl implements PersonDao {

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    public int getPersonCount(){
        String sql = "select count(*) from person";
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForInt(sql);
    }

}
```

One more important piece I had missed was the Dependency Injected Impl instance in the Controller.

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    private PersonDao personDao;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {

        int personCount = personDao.getPersonCount();               
        model.addAttribute("personCount", personCount );

        return "home";
    }

}
```

Comment: if you are using package scanning, you should not need to define this in your xml:
<bean id="personDao" class="com.mypackage.rest.dao.impl.PersonDaoImpl">

Answer (score 0):

The impl class needs to be marked for handling by spring:

```
@Repository
public class PersonDaoImpl implements PersonDao {
```

Now if spring package scanning is being used, it will find this class and process all the @Autowired annotations

Comment: Cheers. Had obviously left this out of the Impl class. Was a piece of the jigsaw I was missing.

Comment: You should not put these spring annotations on the interface class as they dont work and leed to confusion.